# SNMPv3 on OEL8 via Perl Net::SNMP

Tags: net-snmp

I'm trying to get SNMPv3 to work on an Oracle Linux 8 server using Net::SNMP and I'm getting the following error message:

```
SNMPv3 support is unavailable (Required module Crypt/DES.pm not found)
```

The SNMPv3 command and syntax is all correct (an snmpwalk from CLI works as expected). I'm sure I'm missing some package, but I can't seem to find what I need to get SNMPv3 DES support. The script works like a charm using SNMPv1 or 2 - no issue at all.

I have the following SNMP packages already installed:

```
net-snmp.x86_64                      1:5.8-18.el8_3.1
net-snmp-agent-libs.x86_64           1:5.8-18.el8_3.1
net-snmp-devel.x86_64                1:5.8-18.el8_3.1
net-snmp-libs.x86_64                 1:5.8-18.el8_3.1
net-snmp-utils.x86_64                1:5.8-18.el8_3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved - missing Perl modules:

```
Crypt::DES
Digest::SHA
Digest::SHA1
```